# WSO2 - Message processed by all tasks of message processor

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator, wso2-esb

I have only one instance of WSO2 micro integrator running in which I have a JDBC Message Store and a Scheduled Message Forwarding Processor listening to new messages in the message store.

Now when I increase the task count (member count) of the message processor to 2 or more. A message stored in the message processor is processed by all of the tasks. How do I avoid this. I want only one of the message processor tasks to pick up my message.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you observe that a single massage in the message store is processed by all the message processors. What is the micro integrator version you are using in your environment.

Comment: Yes.. I queried the messages in the message store before activating the message processor and there is only one.. but the moment I activate it.. I see two invocations of the endpoint.. the micro integrator version is 1.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have just the same problem in EI 6.5.0. Looking through the source code of the JDBC Message Store shows that there are no measures preventing simultaneous reading and deleting the same records in the message store table by several message processor tasks.

Comment: Yeah I checked too.. Doesn't seem like the handling is there..